# Indoor Maps not displaying all places of a building?

Tags: android, google-indoor-maps

I implemented  indoor maps sample app followed by default api demos.

But in my app only indoor maps is displaying not displayed shops positions like default google application as the attached image.[image]

How I will achieve this.

If anybody have idea ,will you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ,I am asking about how to display shops information in a building like Indoor maps in default Google maps Application.

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly impossible to tell what is your exact problem without looking at your code. My best guess by looking at your map image is that you are missing some of the keypoints. Take a look at the following methods:

```
    // Initialize type of map
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    // Initialize 3D buildings enabled for map view
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(false);

    // Initialize whether indoor maps are shown if available
    map.setIndoorEnabled(false);

    // Initialize traffic overlay
    map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
```

For detailed information please check [this webpage](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mappingDemo.html). It clearly explains what do you need. I hope it will help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi Rahul tq for ur reply.I did all the thing you mentioned above.I am displaying a shopping malll with indoor maps.It is displaying some of the places like restarents and shops info only not all shops inside the mall like google maps.Thai is what my question.How to display all shops info inside mall in Indoor maps like Inbuilt Google Maps App.

Comment: Did you check the link provided?

Comment: Hi Rahul,I did same as the link.But no luck.

Comment: keep playing with methods available. Good luck :)